# Special character to send message in android

Tags: android, clipboard, whatsapp

Is there any way to send a message in Android (such as Whatsapp platform) from a text in clipboard without clicking the send button on the screen? I copied the "Enter" character into my clipboard and paste it into Whatsapp, but it only adds the new line in the screen and not sending the message.
What I need to know is how to copy a "special character" to my clipboard? and if I paste it into WA, it will send the message automatically.

Thanks in advance,
BS

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that's possible, my guess is that whatsapp is listening on keypress and does not parse the actual text you send in.

However it should be possible to do with a device connected with ABD

```
input text 'Paste text on Android Device' (AFTER SDK 23)
adb shell "input keyboard text 'Paste%stext%son%sAndroid%sDevice'" (PRIOR SDK 23)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well actually I'm still looking for another solution.